# Get an element from column and if equal to something put it in another column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe like this:

```
        full_path                     
0   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1\1.txt 
1   C:\Users\User\Desktop\ABC\1.txt 
2   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2\1.txt 
3   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1\1.txt 
4   C:\Users\User\Desktop\ABCD\1.txt 
5   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2\1.txt
```

I want to check if the 5th element of the path is equal to Test 1 and Test2 and create a column like below:

```
        full_path                             folder 
0   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1\1.txt         Test1
1   C:\Users\User\Desktop\ABC\1.txt          
2   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2\1.txt         Test2
3   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1\1.txt         Test1
4   C:\Users\User\Desktop\ABCD\1.txt          
5   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2\1.txt         Test2
```

I tried this command `df['folder']=df["full_path"].str.rsplit("\\").str[4]` but it gives me this output:

```
        full_path                             folder 
0   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1\1.txt         Test1
1   C:\Users\User\Desktop\ABC\1.txt           ABC
2   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2\1.txt         Test2
3   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1\1.txt         Test1
4   C:\Users\User\Desktop\ABCD\1.txt          ABCD 
5   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2\1.txt         Test2
```

I dont want folders that are not Test1 and Test2 to be shown in the folder column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Numpy where:

```
import numpy as np

df['folder'] = np.where(df['full_path'].str.contains('Test'),
                        df['full_path'].str.rsplit('\\').str[4],
                        np.nan
                       )
```

Output:

```
                            full_path    folder
0   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1\1.txt     Test1
1     C:\Users\User\Desktop\ABC\1.txt       NaN
2   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2\1.txt     Test2
3   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test1\1.txt     Test1
4    C:\Users\User\Desktop\ABCD\1.txt       NaN
5   C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2\1.txt     Test2
```